# is it possible to install XFCE4 Desktop on hugging face?

Tags: docker, remote-desktop

in case it is possible to do that, does it mean that I have access to bash terminal with hugging face?

Can I use any python script to install apt and XFCE4 Desktop?

Would this be feasible? Could I connect to said machine using VNC from my Windows 11?

If this is not possible, I would have no choice but to use docker to install XFCE4 Desktop and be able to connect via VNC, but I think that having to use docker would make the VPS very slow.

on telegram I saw a guy who said he had run a minecraft server on hugging face...

I tried to install docker but it gave me some problems

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I don't think I can answer your question, unfortunately, mainly because it sounds like a question for Hugging Face customer support. If you have trouble with an installation script, edit your question to add that and the specific error message you see. If you have trouble using an Inference Endpoint, maybe we can help there?